# Why cookie is missing after page refresh

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The cookie is set when user input value into the textbox.

However, the cookie is missing after page refresh.

Below is my code, can anyone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
      {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
    }
    
    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }
    
    function checkCookie()
    {
    var emailVal=getCookie("email");
    if (emailVal!=null && emailVal!="")
      {
      document.getElementById('emailBox').value =emailVal;
      }
    else 
      {
        var eVal = document.getElementById('emailBox').value;
        
        setCookie("email",eVal,365);
       
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <body>
    <form>
    
    <input type="text" id="emailBox" name="email" onchange="checkCookie()"/>
    
    </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me here -> http://jsfiddle.net/RAZZg/1/

The only thing that I think might be wrong is the placement of your JavaScript code ... try placing it either within the `<body>` tags or add a `<head>` tag :

```
<head>
// your code here
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
```

Update : added the `onload` attribute to the body tag to check the cookie on page load

Comment: there is no value in textbox after refreshing

Comment: the value only changes when you change the value - ie the `checkCookie` function is called `onchange` ... if you want to check for a cookie on load use the `body.onload` event

Comment: you are right, @ManseUK. If I would like to keep cookie value stay in the textbox after refreshing, What change should i do?

Comment: @Acubi see my updated ... using the `onload` event of the `body`